# Computing difference between two datefields in Django Model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, datetime

I have two datefields fields in a Django model, **start_date** and **end_date**. I want to calculate and store the total number of days between the two, which will be used alongside a daily fee to return total cost.

**models.py**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    """Stores the bookings, for example when it was made, the booking date, and the car ID."""
    # Unique ID for this booking.
    start_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Most answers recommend extracting the days function (using start_date.day) but that doesn't work. If a booking starts on November 30, and ends on December 2, the function will return 28 days because it subtracts the integers alone.

Using simple addition and subtraction:

```
duration = end_date - start_date
```

returns an error:

> TypeError: Unsupported Operand type(s) for -: 'DateField' and 'DateField'

I've tried using a function nested within the model, which subtracts each day from end_date until it reaches start_date:

```
    def get_total_days(self):
        """Computes total number of days car will be rented from with a basic While loop."""
        # Create separate instances of start and end day so as not to tamper with db values.
        start_day = self.start_date
        end_day = self.end_date
        days = 0
        while end_day > start_day:
            days += 1
            end_day -= 1
        return days
```

But that raises the error:

> Exception Value: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'datetime.date' and 'int'

Can you help with this?

Comment: *`duration = end_date - start_date`* — Did you put this right beneath the `end_date = ...` line into the class definition? That of course won't work. But on a model instance, that should work just fine: `b = Booking(...)` `b.end_date - b.start_date`. You can of course dress that up as a method or property on the model.

Comment: How do I attach that to a model instance specifically?

Comment: `@property def duration(self): return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days`

Comment: Perfect! That did it thank you. Please add this into to an answer so I can mark this question as complete. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method or property that subtracts the dates *of an instance*:

```
@property
def duration(self):
    return (self.end_date - self.start_date).days
```